# SSRS dynamicaly select field/column using custom code

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Depending on a report parameter I would like to switch the displayed field.

e.g. a normal RS expression would look like this

```
= IIF(Parameters!ReportTypesREPORTTYPEID.Label = 1, Fields!CLIENTGROUP.Value
, IIF(Parameters!ReportTypesREPORTTYPEID.Label = 2, Fields!COSTUNITNUMBER.Value
... etc.. 
)))
```

As I need this code in multiple places (and in multiple variations), I want to move it to a .NET class library.

I've got the basic setup working for referencing a class function:

```
using System;
using System.Security;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Reporting_RS_Lib
{
    public class Functions
    {
        public static int GetReportType(int reportTypeId)
        {
            if (reportTypeId == 0) // will be a case statment
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else {
                return 2;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the if statement, I would like to reference the "Fields"-Collection and return the value of the respective column.

What do I need to reference to achieve the above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work in VB.NET, but not in C#. (C# would not let me access the methods of the fields object..)

```
Imports Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportObjectModel
' 
' Deployment 
' copy dll to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS11.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer\bin
' add the following to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS11.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer\rssrvpolicy.config
' 
'<CodeGroup
'           class="VBFuncs"
'           version="1"
'           PermissionSetName="FullTrust"
'           Name="VBFuncs"
'           Description="Reporting extensions.. ">
'          <IMembershipCondition
'               class="VBFuncs"
'               version="1"
'               Url="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS11.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer\bin\CIDB_Reporting_RS_LibVB.dll"
'       />
'   </CodeGroup>   


Public Class VBFuncs

    Public Function ByReportType(ByVal fieldCollection As Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportObjectModel.Fields, ByVal reportTypeId As Integer) As Object
        Dim fieldName As String = "unkown"
        Dim value As String
        Try
            Select Case reportTypeId
                Case 1
                    fieldName = "Client_Group_ID"
                Case 2
                    fieldName = "Contract_Number"
                Case Else
                    fieldName = "Unkown"
            End Select
            value = fieldCollection(fieldName).Value
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return "Unkown/ or not found reportType " & reportTypeId & " " & fieldName
        End Try
        Return value
    End Function
End Class
```